# Spark SQL - group by after repartitioning

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I want to group all items in a source based on a specified, pre-defined category. The number of items per category could be in the order of millions. The groupBy helps me achieve this, but I want to understand if repartitioning on the product-type before grouping, would be more efficient?

The source for the spark jobs is hive tables. The version of spark is latest 2.4.4. The problem statement for me is that I want to run a customised similarity algorithm for every item with every other item in a given category. So, by the end of this operation, for every item, I would have the 10 most similar items to it.

Since this involves a groupBy operation and since groupBy involves shuffling of data, I thought first I would repartition the data based upon the category. I can even set the number of partitions to the number of categories that I have(in the magnitude of 100s).

Once data is re-partitioned sent on individual workers, running groupBy should be a local operation- if I do the groupBy on the same type. Is this assumption correct?

```java
// For demo, I am reading from CSV. The final source is a hive table
Dataset<Row> rows = spark.read().option("sep", "\t")
                .csv("<some path>")
                .repartition(20, new Column("category"))
                .cache();
Dataset<Row> ids_grouped_by_category = rows.map((MapFunction<Row, Row>) items -> {
           // Some transformation returns a row in the format I need.
            return new-row;
        }, <encoder>)
                .groupBy(functions.col("category"))
                .agg(functions.collect_list("category").as("ids"));
```

At the end of this operation, I have been able to group all item-ids for a given category into a list. Something like this:

```sql
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|category                   |     ids                                  |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|category-1                 | [id1, id2...]                            |
|category-2                 | [idx, idy...]                            |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

I have been able to get the data in the format I need but wanted to understand is this way of doing a group-by correct?
Also, what are the implications of doing a collectList operation? Does it load everything in-memory?

Comment: Did you figure this out?